# iOS 16 default enabled utun0 network interface (VPN?) to 13.13.13.13

Tags: ios, vpn, network-interface, ios16

I just came across this when using our application on the newest iOS 16 beta.

The app can detect wether the user is currently using a VPN service or not. This is done by checking the usual network interfaces used by VPNs like tun, ppp or pptp.

On earlier iOS version this worked correctly but since the iOS 16 beta update it says that the device is currently using a VPN connection even if its not.
So I checked it and it I found that it is using the utun0 network interface with this internet address (13.13.13.13).

Would be nice to have some information on that like what it is used for and wether it will stay in the final release or not.
Or is it simply possible to disable that by any settings made on the iPhone?